# Dask - TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64')

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Tengo un marco de datos cargado con archivos csv y con dask:

```
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
import glob
import pandas as pd
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client()

def load_df_csv():
    
    route1 = r'C:\Users\CSV\S2020.csv'
    route2 = r'C:\Users\CSV\S2021.csv'
    route3 = r'C:\Users\CSV\S2022.csv'
    route4 = r'C:\Users\CSV\S2023.csv'
    
    dtypes = {'ID': 'object','Client': 'object','Duration': 'Int64'}
    
    df = dd.read_csv([route1, route2, route3, route4], usecols=['ID', 'Client','Duration'], 
    sep=',', encoding='latin-1', dtype=dtypes)
    df = df.dropna()
    return df
```

El dataframe:

```
df1 = load_df_csv()

ID Client Duration
AAA  JSA     3
BBB  HYZ     1
CCC  POP     10
DDD  PUM     5
EEE  MOP     23
```

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente código:

`df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = df1, index = np.repeat(df1.index, abs(df1['Duration'])))`

Me sale este siguiente error:

`TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'`

He revisado otras publicaciones similares donde reflejan que el error es por el tipo de dato pero el tipo de dato ya esta cargado como Int64 y no como menciona el error (O :Object).

No puedo arreglar el error, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

me parece que ya sea porque tienes algun NaN o porque `np.repeat` suele tener problemas con los dtypes `index`.

Para el primer caso, habria que revisar si existen NaN. Y ya sea eliminarlos o rellenarlos.

Para el segundo caso, habria que cambiar

`np.repeat(df1b.index, abs(df1['Duration']))`

por

`np.repeat(df1b.index.tolist(), df1['Duration'].abs().tolist())`

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero los índices no tienen ese atributo "tolist()

Comment: @ElthonDanielRivas me parece raro pues ese metodo viene en la referencia oficial (desde la version 1.0).

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.tolist.html

Lo otro que podrias intentar seria `list(df.index)` para convertirlo en lista.

Saludos.